# Getting error while uploading video on s3 using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer

I am getting error while trying to upload video on aws s3 using multer but whenever I am trying to upload image with same code it's working without giving any error

Here's my code

```
const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET,
        Key: req.file.filename
      }

  sharp(req.file.path).resize(100, 100).toBuffer().then(buffer => {
    params.Body = buffer;

    params.Key = 100 + "-" + 100 + "-" + params.Key

    s3.putObject(params, (e, d) => {
      if (e) {
        // reject
      }
    })
  })
```

Could you please help me upload video on s3 with resize feature

getting this error

[image]